# Преобразование каждой четной строки изображения в градации серого цвета

Tags: python, изображения, matplotlib

Задача: Написать функцию,  которая каждую чётную строку изображения переводит в градации серого цвета.
Я написал код, который переводит каждый четный СТОЛБЕЦ в градации серого цвета. Как мне грамотно изменить код, чтобы переводить строки, при условии что изображение не квадратное? Спасибо.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw  # Подключим необходимые библиотеки.

# fig, plt
fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(
    nrows=1, ncols=2,
    figsize=(16, 12)
)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3, hspace=0.3)

# ax1
image = Image.open("p11.jpg")  # Открываем изображение - оригинал.
image_r = Image.open("p11.jpg")  # Открываем изображение - для преобразования.
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image_r)  # Создаем инструмент для рисования.
width = image_r.size[0]  # Определяем ширину.
height = image_r.size[1]  # Определяем высоту.
pix = image_r.load()  # Выгружаем значения пикселей.
step = 5  # Шаг отрисовки серых полос.
for i in range(width):
    if (i / step) % 2 == 0:
         for j in range(height):
            a = pix[i, j][0]
            b = pix[i, j][1]
            c = pix[i, j][2]
            S = (a + b + c) // 3
            draw.point((i, j), (S, S, S))
ax1[0].imshow(image)
ax1[1].imshow(image_r)
ax1[0].axis('off')
ax1[1].axis('off')

del draw
plt.show()
```

Comment: что-то у вас код не соответствует заданию. что у вас за шаг 5? и линии вы рисуете не серым цветом, с усредненным для каждой точки. Не объясните?

Comment: Ну поменяйте циклы местами, а в `if` проверяйте `j`, а не `i`

Comment: @strawdog Насчёт шага верное замечание, а градации серого как-то так и вычисляются - по общей яркости пиксела по всем компонентам. Усреднение с равными весами - самый простой способ, хотя можно и в неравной степени учитывать компоненты, учитывая разную чувствительность человеческого глаза к разным цветовым компонентам.

Comment: @CrazyElf что-то я слово "градации" пропустил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так должно прокатить:

```
for j in range(height):
    if (j / step) % 2 == 0:
        for i in range(width):         
            a = pix[i, j][0]
            b = pix[i, j][1]
            c = pix[i, j][2]
            S = (a + b + c) // 3
            draw.point((i, j), (S, S, S))
```